# Creating a similar product to a patented product

Tags: patent-infringement, design-patent

In reference to the patent: [USD613180](https://www.google.com/patents/USD613180)

I am in interested in creating a similar product that cooks potatoes/vegetables in the microwave, but the name would be different and the design would include a variety of vegetables on the pouch rather than potatoes. The product would also have a similar shape to the pouch.
Is this anywhere near patent infringement?

Answer (score 1):

This is a design patent. What is important here is the ornamental design as described in the figures. Since the figures only describe images of potatoes, you are probably okay with respect to this patent if you use images of other vegetables.

This is not a legal opinion (I'm not a lawyer). I'd also like to caution you that there is the potential for other relevant patents so you would be well served with a patent search and a freedom-to-operate analysis. For instance check out this [page](https://patents.google.com/patent/USD744851S1/en#patentCitations). Lastly, the name of a product is usually protected by trademark and not patent.

Comment: The design patent also covers the "ornamental shape" of the pouch, to the extent their claim is not preempted by a billion examples of prior art, i.e., nearly identical things already being used in that field.

Comment: Everything that isn't drawn with a broken line is included in the ornamental shape. This design patent isn't protecting only the outside shape.